# What is the best way to store big amounts of data, and then write it to file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

We have a Java method that retrieves some columns from a large database table, operates on them, and then reformat each row as CSV. These rows should be written to a single file, which the next system will pick up. (I guess appending a file is time consuming.). We are writing to AWS S3, if that matters.

I don't really know how I should approach this. I could use a `List` or `ArrayList`, and add each row to it, and then write the entire object to file I guess, or maybe I need to loop the object and append the file... But I don't know how to do this in the most efficient way in Java, even after some googling.

So, what is the best way to store big amounts of data, and then write it to file in Java?

Comment: I would read up on batch processing

Comment: If you are using any BufferedWriter, it should not be a problem. As and when you have records available, you can write them to disk. The buffering will take care of it.

Comment: Interesting downvote. I tried to form a easy, searchable question since I didn't find anything myself on Google.

I will try to read up on batch processing, and also BufferedWriter. I have never done anything like this before, and I usually don't develop in Java, so everything here is of great use. Thanks!

Comment: Please understand whether you use any in memory data structure or BufferedWriter, there is a chance of losing data in case of a crash.  If your application can not afford to lose the data in case of crash, I would suggest use something like Kafka. Push all the data in Kafka and let a Kafka consumer create files and upload to S3.

Comment: @VinayAvasthi Thank you Vinay! That is very useful information.